# Java-Stream - How to apply sorting while using Collector groupingBy

Tags: java, java-stream, comparator, collectors, groupingby

I'm using `Collectors.groupingBy` to group may objects into list. Examples are as follows:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student student1 = new Student(98,"man","CHEN",20);
        Student student2 = new Student(100,"man","PETER",20);
        Student student3 = new Student(100,"man","TMAC",21);
        ArrayList<Student> list = Lists.newArrayList(student1, student2, student3);

        Map<Integer, List<StudentDTO>> map = list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getAge,
                Collectors.mapping(e -> new StudentDTO(e.getScore(), e.getName()),
                    Collectors.toList())
            ));

        System.out.println(map);
    }

    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public static class Student {
        private Integer score;
        private String sex;
        private String name;
        private Integer age;
    }

    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public static class StudentDTO {
        private Integer score;
        private String name;
    }

}
```

*Output:*

```
{20=[Test.StudentDTO(score=98, name=CHEN),
     Test.StudentDTO(score=100, name=PETER)],
 21=[Test.StudentDTO(score=100, name=TMAC)]}
```

But my goal is to sort `StudentDTO` by `score` using `Comparator.comparing` with streams. How can I achieve this?

*Desired output:*

```
{20=[Test.StudentDTO(score=100, name=PETER),
     Test.StudentDTO(score=98, name=CHEN)],
 21=[Test.StudentDTO(score=100, name=TMAC)]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sort each list of `StudentDTO` by `score` in descending order, you can use the following comparator:

```
Comparator.comparingInt(StudentDTO::getScore).reversed()
```

And to apply sorting while collecting the result, you can use collector [`collectingAndThen()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen(java.util.stream.Collector,java.util.function.Function)) as the downstream of `groupingBy()`

```
List<Student> students = List.of(student1, student2, student3);

Map<Integer, List<StudentDTO>> map = students.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Student::getAge,
        Collectors.collectingAndThen(
            Collectors.mapping(e -> new StudentDTO(e.getScore(), e.getName()),
                Collectors.toList()),
            list -> { list.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(StudentDTO::getScore).reversed()); return list; }
        )
    ));
```

**Note:** writing the code against concrete implementation makes it inflexible, you might want to learn what are the benefits of using abstractions. See [What does it mean to "program to an interface"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  (I added `import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;`)

```
Map<Integer, List<StudentDTO>> map = list.stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(Student::getAge,
        mapping(e -> new StudentDTO(e.getScore(), e.getName()),
            collectingAndThen(toList(),
                x -> x.stream()
                    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(StudentDTO::getScore).reversed())
                    .collect(toList())))));
```